# (C++) Add custom name to a textfile

Tags: c++

Problem solved, accidently overwrote all the text I had written before. Sorry!

Comment: Place the relevant source code in the question itself. Also make sure it is a [mcve]

Comment: @AndyG Edited the post, thank you!

Comment: You can't modify the `account object;` of the `balance()` function, from the `deposit()` function. Read about variable scope in your C++ resource.

Comment: @chtz Seems like I've kinda hit a brick wall. I am not even sure if this is the smart/best way to do this. I am trying to learn more about classes and how they work, that's why I chose this way. Not sure what I want to do next, rewrite the program and do it in some other way, or try find a fix using this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been overwritten several times, invalidating both answers separately.

Comment: @Quentin Please do, I want it removed aswell.

Comment: @Fotan well if *you* want to remove one of your questions, you can do so by clicking the "delete" link just under the tags. But in the future, please do not "reuse" questions, ask new ones instead.

Comment: @Quentin I know, I messed up. Was not paying attention. Just wanted to copy some of the text and transfer it to the new question, but got lost and pressed save. I have tried to delete it, but it isn't letting me as people have "invested time and effort into answering" it, I flagged it though, so maybe we can get it off.

Answer (score 2):

> 1st: In the account class, the double balance variable, how do I set a
>   default value to it.

You can use uniform initialization

```
double balance{0.0};
```

Or ofc in constructor

```
account(double _balance) : balance(_balance) {}
```

*"Less time to creating menu you should give. More time searching for informations on web you should spend."* -Mr Yoda 2k17

Answer (score 0):

For your question-How do I update the balance variable that is in the account class through my deposit function?

You need to share the account object between the deposit and the balance methods. Currently you have created the account object inside the balance method. For simplicity, you can create the account object as a global variable  in your program so that the deposit method can also update the balance for the same account object. But this would only keep a single account object in the program if that is what you want.